# Which hooks can I use in profile development?

Tags: 7, hooks, distributions

Which hooks are available in profile distribution development? Which other hooks can I use except `hook_install_tasks()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a documented list anywhere, but a quick look at the code suggests these are the available hooks:

- [`hook_install_tasks()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7)
- [`hook_install_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7)
- [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7)
- [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)
- [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)