# Hooks called after installation profile is installed?

Tags: 7, installation-profiles

I'm stuck writing an installation profile.
There are certain things that I want to do only after the installation is completed.

I analyzed top ten installation profiles and checked the documentation, but I couldn't find it. I might be missing something small though.

Is there such hook? If not, how can I execute something at the end of the installation?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I know for `hook_install` and `hook_install_tasks`, and they are not exactly what am I looking for.

They both are called *during* the installation. I want to execute code *after* the installation has been completed.

For example, setup Backup & Migrate schedules. If I do this using `hook_install_tasks()`, the cron run at the end of installation does not seem to work properly/in full, and I get errors when `backup_migrate` tries to write to private directory. Private directory is set up properly and if I just re-run the cron afterwards, it works as it should.

Comment: You can try to run `drupal_cron_run();` before the hook you want to call.

Comment: sounds like you need `hook_enable`

Answer (score 2):

Move your post-installation hooks to a module/part-of-your-profile (that can implement [any hook](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79962/which-hooks-can-i-use-in-profile-development) and move things around even after the system modules is installed).

That way you can overcome problems like [custom block's BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED not working on profile installation hook_install()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104425/custom-blocks-block-visibility-listed-not-working-on-profile-installation-hook), and have a solid last installation step, that makes all your final configs.

bonus * why not even *choose* or make configs in that installation step's form_alter() ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a feature revert done at the end of the installation.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install_tasks().
 */
function MYPROFILE_install_tasks($install_state){
  $tasks = array(
    'MYPROFILE_setup_cleanup' => array(
      'display_name' => st('Cleanup'),
      'display' => FALSE,
      'type' => 'normal'
    ),
  );

  return $tasks;
}

/**
 * Cleanup install task.
 */
function MYPROFILE_setup_cleanup() {
  features_revert();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message, but that's not what I am looking for exactly. I updated the question.

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 could you try setting the private files directory in a feature or in a install task? variable_set('file_private_path', 'mypath');

Comment: I'm setting it up in an install task actually; I create  the folder, set chmod and add `.htaccess`. However, I think that's not the issue.

Comment: Do you also setup file_default_scheme "Default download method"? Or maybe just execute this whole form :) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_file_system_settings/7

Comment: Thanks again. I set everything manually, and I don't setup the file default scheme. I pasted the code I use [here](http://pastebin.com/wtwbdauY). I think it's not the main issue simply because private file system works properly after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Module [Site pre-install and post-install hooks](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_install_hooks) might just do what you need. It's installed as a library and registered with your installation profile. The module provides two hooks: `hook_site_pre_install()` and `hook_site_post_install()`. They are run before the installation tasks and then after *Finished* task.

*From module page:*

> Sample Use Cases
>
> Here are some scenarios where you'd want to use this approach:
>
> You need to configure certain site settings before installing a module that requires those settings (`hook_site_pre_install()`).
>   You need to modify user passwords, tweak menu paths, or adjust settings (such as the site name) that would otherwise be bashed if set in `hook_install()` in the installation profile (`hook_site_post_install()`).

I usually use it to e.g. enable [Shield](https://www.drupal.org/project/shield) module in certain environments at the very end of the installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's hooks
**hook_install** and **hook_install_tasks**

Comment: Thanks for your message, but that's not what I am looking for exactly. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tasks to be run after the "Finished" task by implementing [hook_install_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7).